# Throwing an object at an arch in 2D using C#

Tags: c#, unity3d-2dtools

I am trying to create a 2D game where the user throws a bomb at an arch from point A(which is a fixed point) to point B(which will change constantly). My trouble comes in when I am trying to make the bomb move towards the target location, I cannot seem to get it to go where I touch. I also cannot get it to go there in an arch. Is there anyone that can assist me in solving this problem. Other help that I have researched is for a 3D situation and I have trouble converting it into a 2D model.

Below are the two scripts that are being used together.

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

public int[] distanceToThrow;
public int[] bombToThrow;
public GameObject bomb;
public Transform throwOrigin;
public Vector2 throwSpeed;
public float gravity;
//public Transform throwPointPos;
public Vector2 throwDestination;
public float flightSpeed;
public float throwTimer;
public float throwResetTimer;
public float landingTime;
public Vector2 touchPos;

private BombController theBomb;
private Rigidbody2D bombRB;

//private Camera theCamera;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    //theCamera = FindObjectOfType<Camera>();
    theBomb = FindObjectOfType<BombController>();
    bombRB = theBomb.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (throwTimer > 0)
    {
        throwTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        // Using a single touch as control - Letholor
    }
    else if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        touchPos = new Vector2(touch.position.x, touch.position.y);
        Debug.Log("You are touching at position: " + touchPos);
       /* Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touchPos);
        RaycastHit hitResult;
        Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitResult);*/
        Vector2 throwDestination = touchPos;
        Debug.Log("Throw destination is " + throwDestination);
        SendBomb(throwDestination);
    }

}

public void SendBomb(Vector2 throwDestination) {

    if (throwTimer > 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("Cooling down.");
        return;
    }

    throwTimer = throwResetTimer;
    Debug.Log("Throwing bomb to " + throwDestination);
    //Instantiate(bomb, throwOrigin.position, throwOrigin.rotation);
    GameObject newBomb = Instantiate(bomb, throwOrigin.position, throwOrigin.rotation);
    newBomb.GetComponent<BombController>().SetThrowDestination(touchPos - throwDestination);
   }
```

}

```
public class BombController : MonoBehaviour {

public int bombTimer;
public float explosionRadius;
public int resetTimer;
public bool exploded;
public Animation anim;
private Rigidbody2D bombRigidbody;
public float bombSpeed;
public float gravity;
private PlayerController thePlayer;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    bombRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    thePlayer = FindObjectOfType<PlayerController>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground" || collision.gameObject.tag == "Bomb")
    {
        bombRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
    }
}

public void Detonate()
{
    anim.Play("explode");
    exploded = true;
}

public void SetThrowDestination(Vector2 throwDestination)
{
    bombRigidbody.velocity = throwDestination * bombSpeed;
}
```

}

Comment: Is the bomb moving at all? Is the shape of the trajectory an arc (even if not quite right)? Is it "falling" upwards or downwards?

Comment: It's falling down and moving forward because I added force to it in the bomb controller script. It, however, does not more where I want it to. It goes forward by the move speed and down by the gravity so it falls in the same place every time, no matter where you touch the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Things to check:

- Make sure your Rigidbody2D has its **Gravity Scale** property set to **1** and the **Body Type** to **Dynamic**.
- Check you give a value to  Edit -> Project Settings -> Physics 2D -> Gravity -> Y (it's in Newtons, so **-9.8** sounds about right).
- Since [**velocity** should not be edited](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-velocity.html), use [AddForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html) to make it move in the direction you want.
- Make sure the direction vector is calculated as destination - origin (delta position), or in your case **throwDestination - throwOrigin**. Any multipliers should be applied to the direction vector (e.g. **bombSpeed**).
- Remove any direct manipulation to **velocity** and let the physics engine do its thing.

All of that should make the object move in the direction you want. If it doesn't, then there's probably a problem with one of the vectors or maybe the bombSpeed is too low (*"Add zeroes until it breaks"*). Try setting the vector values manually and make sure they're not being modified by any other section of the code.

Comment: I will look when I get home today. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I hope you find it useful =]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what I had done but when I implemented those changes to my script. Now the bomb just spawns and falls directly downward. I could not put in the line bombRigidbody.velocity.y -= gravity...When I tried to, it would not let me. It said "Cannot modify the return calue of Rigidbody2D.velocity becasue it is not a variable.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry for the trouble that I feel I'm causing.

Comment: Oh, no worries. We're here to help. Ok, so the fact that the object is falling means that it is being affected by gravity. If it just falls downwards, it's because the velocity is not interacting with the object. Maybe bombSpeed is 0 or throwDestination is (0, 0). I'll have a look later.

Comment: I did change the bomb speed to a positive number. I even tried going up to test insane numbers like 200 or the speed, it continued to fall immediately as it was spawned. The only difference I noticed when I changed the gravity was how slow it fell.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'll try now. I didn't see it.

Comment: I have edited my code above to reflect the changes that I have made.

Comment: The bomb now does what It had dome before. it will move depending on the gravity and the speed. no matter my touch position.

Comment: You need to remove this line: `bombRigidbody.velocity.y -= gravity;` and make this line: `newBomb.GetComponent<BombController>().SetThrowDestination(throwDestination);` like this: `newBomb.GetComponent<BombController>().SetThrowDestination(touchPos - throwDestination);`

Comment: Yes, those changes are implemented in the above edit.

Comment: I still see this in `Update()`: `bombRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(bombSpeed, bombRigidbody.velocity.y - gravity);` You need to remove that line altogether, because it overrides the physics engine. Remove everything from `Update()`.

Comment: Ahhhhhh ok. I'll try that. Thank you for sticking with me here.

Comment: Hahah, no worries. This conversation will get removed later, so I'll update my answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: I'm currently at work but I will try when I get home.

Comment: I have edited my code to correctly run the code that we were talking about in the above. Unfortunately it does not run properly still. It will spawn the bomb directly in the hit box and nothing more. It will not move along the x or the y axis.

Comment: OK, now let's have a look at the physics engine. Your rigidbody2d should have its gravityScale property set to 1. Also, you should have gravity set to a sensible number in Edit -> Project Settings -> Physics. The body type should be dynamic. Mass should be greater than 0 and constraints should be set to none. You can modify all that from the editor. Have a look and let's see the results.

Comment: Ok i got a positive and a negative. Positive is that if I change the x on the gravity scale, it moves a little. Negative is that I cannot tell it to go where my finger has been pressed, also when the bomb hits the ground, it just continues to slide along the x axis forever.

Comment: Nice, we're moving forward. The bomb doesn't stop in x because you're not telling it to do it. You can do that through materials, but I would say just set velocity to 0 when it enters the collider. Also, you need to set the direction vector as `target - origin`. In your code, it would be something like `newBomb.GetComponent<BombController>().SetThrowDestination(t‌​ouchPos - throwDestination);`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't edit my PlayerController script to display that change. I have adjusted it.

Comment: I'm stupid. `throwDestination` _is_ `touchPos`. You need to do `throwDestination - throwOrigin` (assuming they both have a value.)

Comment: My throw origin is a vector2 and throw destination is a transform.            newBomb.GetComponent<BombController>().SetThrowDestination(throwDestination -  new Vector2(throwOrigin.position.x, throwOrigin.position.y));
 I added that line of code instead. The bomb does not respond differently. Was I supposed to keep the x gravity up above 0. I changed it back when the bomb kept sliding around.

Comment: Reading through [Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-velocity.html) on velocity, **The value is not usually set directly but rather by using forces**. Apparently, we've been doing it wrong. `Rigidbody2D.AddForce(destination - origin)` seems to be the way to go. Give it a try.

Comment: I don't have a method named AddForce. Do I just let it generate an empty method?

Comment: It is a member of [Unity's Rigidbody2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html). `bombRigidbody.velocity = throwDestination * bombSpeed;` should become `bombRigidbody.AddForce(throwDestination * bombSpeed)`.

Comment: When I added...bombRigidbody.AddForce = (throwDestination * bombSpeed);...I got the error that I cannot assign to 'AddForce' because it is a 'method group'.

Comment: Sorry. I was still trying to set it as an operand.

Comment: I'm sorry my friend, but it is once again time for me to begin my trip to work. I will pick this back up when I am home and able to turn on my computer again.

Comment: Is there something I missed?

Comment: Can you explain the train of thought and the process I need to take to me and I'll try to figure it out more.

Comment: I am going to continue to look at the documentation for AddForce and see if I can figure out what's going on there. Thank you for your help. I know it took a lot longer than anyone expected.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of more help =S

Comment: You've been more help than you know. I have been self taught for a couple of years now. I'm still trying to crawl out of the weeds and understand everything that I need to do in order to become a good programmer and game developer.